# How to generate 64 Bit entropy token in Java

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a token which have 64 bit entropy, please share your idea how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean [`Random.nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong--), or it's more random cousin [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)?

Comment: I'm using token base session authentication, but I'm generating random string but its not passing security scan test, they suggest me to generate 64 bit entropy token

Comment: yes I think it will work, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[])`  this should give you a secure random number of whatever byte length you need.

Comment: I need random string token, you can test generated token in this site https://apps.cygnius.net/passtest/

also check crack time

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

This will generate a random string of 15 ASCII characters, excluding space.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
char[] buf = new char[15];
for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
    buf[i] = (char)(33 + rnd.nextInt(127 - 33));
System.out.println(buf);
```

*Sample Output* (with entropy according to https://apps.cygnius.net/passtest/)

```
E%`}%/1sj\a*c6R     entropy: 82.353
e.vu{c#l0<kLVSv     entropy: 76.322
M-VyT?lS~mfv?KR     entropy: 87.385
/:qW8;GnG4g`DgU     entropy: 91.172
_:NIvU5HdLS/2[b     entropy: 83.262
(mv/*i9<lG:L#Z:     entropy: 89.5
mwao4,H~3'kxhTM     entropy: 86.711
?|a<(Ulm/D-:j_f     entropy: 82.091
4.^7u_T"Xk{}([>     entropy: 83.459
(fd?X4usO7No$m_     entropy: 73.448
```